# recursion not stopping after view gets popped from navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk

I have a recursive call to perform some logged movements from user. While the animation is performed using the following recursive call, if user presses the back button to pop the viewcontroller out of the stack, somehow the animation doesn't stop and I can see the log entries (representing different log movements) on the console.

```
-(void)replayNextLog {
    if ((replayLogIndex < [lastTurnGameLogList count]-1) && (!skipReplayButtonWasPressed)) {
        float delayToNextReplay;

        //the replayLogIndex ends with count-1 because the last one is empty due to the last empty line
        NSDictionary *logEntryDict = [lastTurnGameLogList objectAtIndex:replayLogIndex];

        for (id key in logEntryDict) {
            if ([key isEqualToString:kGuessMoveTypeLetterButton]) {

            } else if ([key isEqualToString:kGuessMoveTypeRevealHint]) {

            } else if ([key isEqualToString:kGuessMoveTypeReset]) {

            } else if ([key isEqualToString:kGuessMoveTypePass]) {

            } else if ([key isEqualToString:kGuessMoveTypeShuffle]) {

            }
        }

        replayLogIndex++;

        // Recursive call
        [self performSelector:@selector(replayNextLog) withObject:nil afterDelay:delayToNextReplay];
    }
}
```

Could it be because of any leaks in the view controller? For your convenience, let me tell you that I am not reaching the dealloc method of the VC.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Obaid

Comment: You might want to post the code of your VC so that we have some context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to control the animation/recursion, possibly using an instance variable, and start it from within the `viewDidAppear` method and stop it from the `viewDidDisappear` method.  The view controller isn't necessarily destroyed just because it's popped from the navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same idea as work around but I feared that it might not be the cleanest way to achieve it. Anyways, it works :)

Comment: BTW, isn't it obvious that the view gets unloaded once its popped from the stack?

Comment: @ObaidAbdulMaroof Apple differentiate between loading/unloading (that can happen pretty much any time) and appearing/disappearing (that can happen when the user presses things to make it happen).